# Show for a particular page ID only title and short summary

Tags: theme-development

```
$id = 25; 
$post = get_page($id); 
$title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $title, $content;
```

The above code shows title and full content, but I want to show the short summary only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

the short summary function is `the_excerpt` or `get_the_excerpt`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Or

```
<?php echo  $post->post_exerpt; ?>
```